# EXTJS method errors out on string beginning with colon character

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, extjs

I've inherited some EXTJS code on top of an ASP.NET MVC application and I'm trying to trace an error that occurs when a Ext.msg.prompt box has a string with a ":" character in front of it. Here's the method where the error seems to occur:

```
  var casePrompt = function() {
    Ext.Msg.prompt("Numb", "", function(btn, text) {
        if (btn == "ok") {
            numbID = text.trim().toUpperCase();
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: "/location/method/" + numbID,
                method: "GET",
                callback: function(options, success, response) {
                    var reply = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                    if (success) {
                        listOpen(reply.Data);
                    } else {
                        errorMsg(reply, function(button, text) { numbID = ""; });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

If a number goes into the box as expected, everything works fine. However, if someone enters that same number, or any valid number, with a ":" in front of it, the method errors out before it even returns to the controller. The error only says "Microsoft JScript compilation error: Syntax error" and highlights the following code in ext-all-debug.js:

```
doDecode = function(json){
     return eval("(" + json + ;)');
}
```

Has anyone seen this before and know of a way to catch this error? I've tried to step through this in VS2010 without any luck yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Get a hold on the value of that json variable and I guess that the problem will be obvious - probably a malformatted json response from the server. 
If this is a number field and not a string, both client and server should really do some validation here!
Maybe the server sends the error message in the response body (plain text or html), and that's why the doDecode fails.

Comment: Yes, there's basically no error handling on the text string, so it just mashes through whatever gets put in. I agree that this needs validation on multiple levels. Hm.

Comment: Maybe the value is not wrapped in quotes? Then `:234324` would definitely throw an error if fed into doDecode. `(:234324)` is not valid Javascript, `"(:234324)"` is (because it's simply a string)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just putting validation using regular expressions on the text string to catch anything that doesn't match a valid character. This took care of the colon and any other character, so mistaecko was right that it needed client side validation. This seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you for your comments!